# AJAX text response comes with space between each characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am stuck with weird problem. I have text file which has the data in **`JSON`** format. When I make an **`AJAX`** call to it, it gets the response with space between each characters.

**My code:**

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  async: false,
  dataType: "text",
  url: escape(url),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("ajax success");        
    var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));    
    console.log("Data has: "+ result);
  }
});
```

How ajax brings back the data is like this 
[There are space between characters]

[image]

And also the encoded symbols in the text for example < > are not decoding back.

Please help

If I place the json text directly in place of data in my above code and execute on browser console. It works perfectly fine.

```
[{"MenuJson":null,"menu_en":{"service":"\u003cp\u003eRoasted coalfish fillet \u003cbr/\u003ein creamed dill sauce, served with\u003cbr/\u003eleaf lettuce in sweet cream dressing\u003cbr/\u003eand boiled potatoes\u003cbr/\u003e\u003cbr/\u003eFruits from the market\u003cbr/\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003c/p\u003e","buffet":"\u003cp\u003eCreamed parsnips soup\u003cbr/\u003eSautéed gnocchi,\u003cbr/\u003eserved with cheese sauce\u003cbr/\u003e\u003c/p\u003e"},"menu_de":{"service":"\u003cp\u003eGebratenes Seelachsfilet\u003cbr/\u003eDillrahmsauce \u003cbr/\u003eBlattsalate, \"Sylter Dressing\"\u003cbr/\u003eSalzkartoffeln\u003cbr/\u003e.\u003cbr/\u003eObst vom Markt \u003cbr/\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003c/p\u003e","buffet":"\u003cp\u003ePastinakenrahmsuppe\u003cbr/\u003eSautierte Gnocchis \"Gärtnerin Art\"\u003cbr/\u003eKäsesauce \u003cbr/\u003e\u003c/p\u003e"}}]
```

Comment: where's the code you are using to read the response ??

Comment: @mrid I edited the post with my code. sorry for that, new to stackoverflow.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` is completely redundant. You just convert from JSON to a string, and back again. This does nothing useful. But also, `datatype: "text"` is clearly incorrect if you're saying the file contains JSON. Try `dataType: "json"` instead. And lastly `async:false` is bad practice - it just locks up the browser so the user can't click anything while the request is in progress, creating a bad user experience, and since you're using the success callback correctly, it has no purpose. It's also deprecated and you can expect browser to remove the feature in future.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your suggestion. I am basically doing in sharepoint framework. Therefore, async doest have any effect on browser. datatype json gets the data in unreadable format. I have already tried all the suggestions you have mentioned. Sadly, it did not help me.

Comment: "Therefore, async doest have any effect on browser"...whether you make the ajax call async or not has nothing whatsoever to do with sharepoint, which is a server-side application. Your browser will make the request async if you tell it you, and not async if you tell it to. Sharepoint has no control over that, there is no sharepoint code involved in what you have written above. The async-ness in this context is related to the thread of control in JavaScript, within the user's browser, and is unrelated to the way in which the server-side code gets executed when receiving the request.

Comment: If dataType: json returns the data unreadable (what exactly does it look like, btw, in that case?) then clearly it's not really returning proper JSON. Sounds like the server-side is possible doing something weird. What content type header do you get back in the response? If the server returned exactly your sample data as shown in the question, then `dataType: "json"` would work no problem.

Comment: @ADyson content-encoding: gzip
x-content-type-options: nosniff
allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-length: 491
microsoftsharepointteamservices: 16.0.0.6927
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
content-type: text/plain
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: private,max-age=0
etag: "{F5B571FE-69C1-4C01-B233-3A548DC22446},1"
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-headers: content-type

Comment: so it's returning text/plain as the content type, but it should be returning application/json

Comment: @ADyson Thanks you very much for your suggestions. I figured out. Kindly see my answer post.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out.

While creating text file in the server text encoding was wrong. I created text file with UTF8 encoding in the server via console application.

Final Ajax call was like this

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',async: false,contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8", dataType: "text",url: escape(url),
success: function(data) {
  console.log("ajax success");              
  var result = JSON.parse(data);     
  console.log("Data has: "+ result)});
```